# How to fill data in a dataframe based on first column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am making a dataframe in Python. I need to fill in this dataframe by taking information from a dataframe that I already have.

For example:

DF1 header-  `License # | color | make | model`

DF2 header-  `License # | mpg`

Then lets say that each car would have city and highway mpg, so each license # would appear twice.

If I already have a dataframe that has data for the first four columns, and I calculated the mpg column, how can I add columns like color, make, and model just by knowing the license #. Because each car has multiple mpgs, I cannot just add the color make and model columns as there are more entries in the second dataframe.

Is there some way that I could maybe make a dictionary out of the first dataframe and fill data in DF2 by knowing the license #? Or is there some other way that I could go about this?

Comment: Please share a sample dataframe input with expected output in the question itself. It makes it easier to understand the problem.

Comment: Please read this [mre]